# Matrix has a voltage drop on a coil that should not be receiving any current

Tags: transistors, electromagnetism, electromagnetic

I am making a matrix of electromagnets (each with about 120 Ohms resistance) and I am using a circuit like this for the columns (low side of the switch):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuBKXm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For the high side (rows of the matrix) here is what I am using:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2EV26.png)</sup>

:

I have a test 2x2 matrix hooked up right now (with two rows and two columns as shown) When I power 0,0 (i.e. signals on col 0 and row 0 are high, the others low) I still get about a +4V drop on the coil at (0,1), which is definitely not what I expected. Does anyone know why? My guess is because of the lack of diodes but since the 4V is in the + direction I'm not too sure. Another guess is that my resistor values are wrong, but to be honest I'm not sure at all how to figure that out.

EDIT: After further probing, the coil at (0,1) also turns on and has a voltage reading of about 3.8V, as well as the coil at (1,1) with a voltage drop of 3.8V

Comment: I hope that you've only drawn your 12V supply upside-down and not actually connected it that way ...

Comment: @brhans oh yeah it is upside down whoops, I made that real quick. I will fix it so that the positive is connected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use diodes to steer the current then you will have multiple paths of current flow through all the electromagnets. Yes, there will be one electromagnet that receives a direct connection but, because that row is "grounding" several other electromagnets, current from the active column driver can flow to several series electromagnets and back to the grounded row. Just draw it out and use a crayon or something similar to plot the current flow. Like this: -

[image]

The purple electromagnet is the one that is directly driven and the light blue electromagnets are an example of series electromagnets that will also take current flow. I've only shown one path that the extra current will flow but there are many other paths. You need diodes to prevent this from happening.